# How do I access a .ipynb file? Do I neeed to download jupyter notebook in order to do this?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm doing the SQL course on coursera

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install Jupyter Notebook as a library for [python](https://jupyter.org/install).

But also you can try open and run your file, for example, in [Google Collab](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/intro.ipynb#recent=true).